# Radiobutton on Razor page does not return value

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, radio-button

The value for Gender is set (checked) to Male when the page is rendered, however when the submit button is pressed the value returned for Gender is null, regardless if Male or Female is checked.

The Razor page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    Male: @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male")
                    Female: @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female")
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

The CS page:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Test.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string? Gender { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            Gender = "Male";

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {

            var test = Gender;

            return Page(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to allow the user of the program to check Male or Female and return that value to the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [BindProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.bindpropertyattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) attribute:

```
[BindProperty]
public string? Gender { get; set; }
```